# One Drive for Business Connector - Create File (binary troubles)

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-logic-apps, filereader, onedrive

Hello I have made an angular site that connects to a logic app api one drive connector.
Here is a link to how the connector works on Microsoft's site [actions-create-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveforbusiness/#create-file).

It says that content should be passed in as a binary. Here is my current code.

```
fileUpload(upload: any) {
    for(let file of upload.target.files) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        if (reader.result !== null) {
          this.dataService.uploadFile(this.dataService.customer, file.name, reader.result).subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (data.message === 'Created File') {
              this.fetchFileListById(this.dataService.path[this.dataService.path.length - 1]);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The upload is passed in by a file input html element. Whenever I upload an office doc it seems to go through but, when I download and reopen it's corrupted. Is this not the proper way to convert a file to binary and pass it to this connector?

When I check the run history. The name and directory are correct that are sent to the app but the file content(reader.result) looks like a ton of random symbols and question mark boxes.

Comment: I’m confused, are you using LogicApps or not? If not, please remove the tag. If you are, show us your flow. Your code doesn’t look like it has anything to do with LogicApps.

Answer (score 0):

May need more details. "Create File" is a task in logic apps. how do you pass that from Angular? Do you have an HTTP trigger before that?

you may need one of these logiapps functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type#converter-functions

probably the binary()